# mypy - Wrapping an overloaded function while keeping the overloaded signature

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to get the typing right for an overloaded function while retaining the overloaded signature for the wrapper function. To do this, I have to also define overloads for the wrapper function, which then causes issue when calling the wrapped function, since there's no matching overload variant for a call that matches all possible overload variants.

Is there any way to get around this or will I just have to fix all these with `type: ignore[call-overload]`?

```py
from typing import overload


@overload
def update_resource(id_: str, *, data: str) -> None:
    ...


@overload
def update_resource(id_: str, *, config: str) -> None:
    ...


def update_resource(
    id_: str, *, data: str | None = None, config: str | None = None
) -> None:
    pass


@overload
def wrapped_update_resources(id_: str, *, data: str) -> None:
    ...


@overload
def wrapped_update_resources(id_: str, *, config: str) -> None:
    ...


def wrapped_update_resources(
    id_: str, *, data: str | None = None, config: str | None = None
) -> None:
    # there's more going on here, but it's not relevant to the issue
    return update_resource(id_=id_, data=data, config=config)  # type: ignore
```

Mypy will report the following:

```
file.py:33: error: No overload variant of "update_resource" matches argument types "str", "Optional[str]", "Optional[str]"
file.py:33: note: Possible overload variants:
file.py:33: note:     def update_resource(id_: str, *, data: str) -> None
file.py:33: note:     def update_resource(id_: str, *, config: str) -> None
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the only correct solution is to use valid calls inside your wrapper, which you currently aren't. As you correctly stated, there is no variant of `update_resource` that matches the way you call it. Here is essentially how I would do it:

```py
def wrapped_update_resources(
    id_: str, *, data: str | None = None, config: str | None = None
) -> None:
    if data is not None:
        if config is not None:
            raise RuntimeError("Both present")
        return update_resource(id_=id_, data=data)
    if config is not None:
        return update_resource(id_=id_, config=config)
    raise RuntimeError("Both missing")
```

I realize this is much more involved than your one-liner, but it is also more consistent. If you don't like it, then silencing type checkers in this instance is the way to go.

One could also argue that it is questionable whether or not you do need *both* functions to be public and defined with such specific interfaces, but this only you can answer. I can imagine a situation where you construct a private helper function that does the checks I presented above, but doesn't have those overloaded signatures. That way any wrapper can safely call it with all arguments.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution makes this being a wrapper quite pointless, since this logic is already happening in the wrapped function. And I need to both of them be public since they represent the async implementation and synchronous wrapper of an API respectively. A private helper function also would not help in this case, since it still wouldn't type check properly.